# Multi Column header for a UITableView with Multiple Columns

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have created a UITableView with multiple columns to display a Football League Table.  Now what I really need is a header to label each column which will ideally sit at the top of the table view.  How would I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could create a custom UIView and set it as the first section header of your UITableView. Return it in your UITableViewDelegate's tableView:viewForHeaderInSection: method. You simply need to design it so that it aligns with the "columns" inside your custom cells.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of setting it as the header for your first `UITableView` section, it would make more sense in your situation to set it as the header to your entire table. This can be done with the [`tableHeaderView`](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableView/tableHeaderView) property of `UITableView`. For example:

```
UIView *myHeaderView = ...
[myTableView setTableHeaderView:myHeaderView];
```

Comment: As you could guess by my +1 I preferred this. But created a UIView to my likings in interface builder, created an IBOutlet in my interface and included it in viewDidLoad `[self.tableView setTableHeaderView:viewHeader];` and presto.

Answer (score -6):

This is sort of a weird interface for an iPhone app, assuming you are trying to replicate the look and feel of an HTML table, with headings, cells and etc.

If this is what you want, why not just use a `UIWebView` object to display your table?

Comment: Because I am doing it with a UITableView

Comment: A better question might have been "What's the easiest way to build a multi-column table in iOS?", but that's not what the OP asked! Since there's no further context, we probably shouldn't assume what they're trying to achieve.