# Multiple Column Table

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios5, multiple-columns

Very basic question and requirement but cannot find any example in iOS 5 how to create multiple column table in iOS 5.

Anyone knows how to?

Note: Not xib, I am working with storyboard.

Looking forward to your answers.

Comment: Didn't [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/791628/593709), [this](http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2008/08/table-view-tutorial-tableview-cell.html), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4791451/593709) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5932562/593709) help you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "visual" way of doing it, as in other languages, not even in Xcode 4.3 which I just downloaded and tested. You will need to follow one of the tutorials linked by Adil in his comment to do it in code.